# the text inside the mddropdownmenu is not showing up... kivymd

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

so i have basically copied the code in the documentation but the text is not showing up and the same thing happens in my app too.
no idea why

Documentation code:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu

KV = """
#:import toast kivymd.toast.toast

MDScreen:

    MDDropDownItem:
        id: dropdown_item
        text: 'Item 0'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .6}
        current_item: 'Item 0'
        on_release: app.menu.open()

    MDRaisedButton:
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .3}
        text: 'Check Item'
        on_release: toast(dropdown_item.current_item)
"""


class Example(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.screen = Builder.load_string(KV)
        menu_items = [{"text": f"Item {i}"} for i in range(5)]
        self.menu = MDDropdownMenu(
            caller=self.screen.ids.dropdown_item,
            items=menu_items,
            position="center",
            width_mult=4,
        )
        self.menu.bind(on_release=self.set_item)

    def set_item(self, instance_menu, instance_menu_item):
        self.screen.ids.dropdown_item.set_item(instance_menu_item.text)
        instance_menu.dismiss()

    def build(self):
        return self.screen


Example().run()
```

the output is:

1. the main screen ---> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfEY4.png)
2. after clicking the dropdownitem ---> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVSmm.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `MDDropdownMenu` use [recycle view](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.recycleview.html) to present children and so they need to specify the viewclass or the widget type you want to display
I just update your code to use `OneLineListItem` to be `MDDropdownMenu` children

```py
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineIconListItem
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu

KV = '''
<IconListItem>

    IconLeftWidget:
        icon: root.icon


MDScreen

    MDDropDownItem:
        id: drop_item
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
        text: 'Item 0'
        on_release: app.menu.open()
'''


class IconListItem(OneLineIconListItem):
    icon = StringProperty()


class Test(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.screen = Builder.load_string(KV)
        menu_items = [
            {
                "viewclass": "IconListItem",
                "icon": "git",
                "text": f"Item {i}",
                "height": dp(56),
                "on_release": lambda x=f"Item {i}": self.set_item(x),
            } for i in range(5)
        ]
        self.menu = MDDropdownMenu(
            caller=self.screen.ids.drop_item,
            items=menu_items,
            position="center",
            width_mult=4,
        )
        self.menu.bind()

    def set_item(self, text_item):
        self.screen.ids.drop_item.set_item(text_item)
        self.menu.dismiss()

    def build(self):
        return self.screen


Test().run()
```

Comment: it did show the items but is giving a weird space https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8t7I.png

Comment: and i am not able to select any of the items after the menu opens up

Comment: Check the updated code it should works for you if you need any change any `MDDropdownMenu` you can check the doc here https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/menu/index.html#center-position

Comment: well thanks there were some problems in binding and the set_item function...

Comment: My solution was update to kivy 2.2.1 and kivymd 1.2.0.dev()
https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started/

kivy 2.1.0 was not showing